import that works from main module or directly
TL;DR How do I make an import resolvable regardless of whether a file is run directly or is itself imported by a parent module?
This is not the same as the million questions about importing modules from parent packages. I've had a hard time finding an exactly equivalent question, so if I've missed something, please point me in the right direction. On the other hand, maybe it means that what I'm trying to do doesn't make sense.
I have a VSCode project based in pkg:
pkg\
    main.py
    __init__.py
    subpkg\
        foo.py
        bar.py
        __init__.py

Suppose foo.py contains something like this:
from bar import baz

def something_intended_to_be_called_from_main():
    baz()

def quick_and_dirty_tests_while_programming():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    quick_and_dirty_tests_while_programming()

And suppose that main.py just contains import subpkg.foo.
Here's the problem. If I run foo.py directly, the import is resolved. But if I run main.py, the import is not resolved because bar is not in pkg. I can address this by changing the import line in foo.py to from subpkg.bar import baz, but then it won't be resolved when running it directly.
Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do? I mean, I guess I could put in a try ... except block with both resolutions, but that seems hackish (even more than including quick and dirty tests in submodules).

Firstly, if main.py only contains codes import foo, I think it should raise ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo', unless the condes in main.py were import subpkg.foo, then it would raise ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bar'
When you run main.py under pkg directory, Python will treat the current path  ../pkg as root path to look for any package you want to import under it. To change this root path and satisfy your need, you can set $PYTHONPATH to the path of subpkg directory in terminal with command like:
export PYTHONPATH="./subpkg"

If you're not family with terminal operation, and you're using idle like vscode, create a directory .vscode under the root path of your program, like:
.vscode
pkg\
main.py
__init__.py
subpkg\
    foo.py
    bar.py
    __init__.py

And a file named settings.json under .vscode directory with content:
{
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "path of subpkg directory"
    },
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "path of subpkg directory"
    },
    "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "path of subpkg directory"
    }
}

Then you can run your python file directly with vscode, cause vscode will automatically set PYTHONPATH env for you.
And a file named launch.json under .vscode directory, if you're prefer debug function of vscode, and add following content:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Current File",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "path of subpkg directory"
            }
        }
    ]
}

If you don't know what is the path of subpkg directory, run your main.py with codes:
from pathlib import Path
print(Path(__file__).parent.joinpath("subpkg"))


Whoops, you're right. main.py contains import subpkg.foo; my typo. Question fixed. As for this solution, I'm not familiar with that (scripting?) language; how do I test it? But it would also seem somewhat hackish to have to use that in each subpkg file.

@LukeSawczak for system like linux or os, you can run command export PYTHONPATH="./subpkg"  in a terminal and then run your python file with command like python main.py. In the same terminal, you can  just run this for once and don't need to add it in each subpkg file. I also updated my answer, but it would be better if you let us know how you run your program
